# retrieve individuals from OWL file using sparql query Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, owl

This is part of my CS.owl that shows individual DropBox of class CloudService.

```xml
 <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/SaaS-24-03-2013.owl#DropBox -->
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SaaS-24-03-2013;DropBox">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;CloudService"/>
        <hasPriceModel rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;Freemium"/>
        <hasDeliveryModel rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;Software-as-a-Service"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I need to retrieve individuals (such as DropBox) of class CloudService using Jena. 
The following SPARQL query runs perfectly in Protege 4.3. It retrieves many services including "DropBox". 
I need to run it using Jena. Here is my code

```java
        String query = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
                        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "+
                            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "+
                                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                                    "PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/SaaS-24-03-2013.owl#> "+
                                        "SELECT ?Service "+
                                                " WHERE {"+
                                            " ?Service  a   :CloudService} "; 
           model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
                model.read("ontologies/CS.owl");
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(SparqlQuery);
                QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
                com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();         
    qe.close();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
}
```

The query returns empty result under the column header
While it works on Protege and returns results (including DropBox)
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed the execution `qe` then tried to print results. Code must finish working with the results calling `qe.close`.  Move the `ResultSetFormatter` line.

Comment: I have also used the following to display the results  while(results.hasNext()) {
   QuerySolution qs = results.next();
   System.out.println(qs); }

Comment: If you have another question, either open a new thread, or if it's closely related modify the existing question please.

Comment: Please do not edit questions after they have been answered when the change invalidates the answer.